# Laravel can't get x-editable to function

Tags: php, laravel, x-editable

I'm trying to get the inline editing popup **x-editable** to work in my Laravel app. I have a stripped-down test case to just get this to function, but can't get a response from it. The page looks fine, a list of linked names from the database, but they are unresponsive.

I installed the x-editable bootstrap libraries and can see in the console that they are found and fine. I'm not getting any response from the link (it should popup and edit box). No errors, all looks fine, but something is broken. Any ideas?

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\investment_account;
use App\investment_line_item;

class popupEditController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $investment_item = investment_account::find(1)->investment_line_item;
        $investment_line_items = investment_line_item::all();


    return view('popupEdit', compact('investment_item','investment_line_items'));       

    }

    public function updatePosition(Request $request)
    {

   } 
}
```

Routes (web.php):

```
Route::get('/popupEdit', 'popupEditController@index');
Route::post('/popupEdit',  'popupEditController@updatePosition');
```

Blade:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

<link href="bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>


@foreach ($investment_line_items as $single_item)
<a href="#" id="investmentName" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ $single_item->id }}" data-title="Edit investment">{!! $single_item->investment_name !!}</a></br>
@endforeach

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$.fn.editable.defaults.send = "always";

  $.fn.editable.defaults.params = function (params) 
  {
   params._token = $("#_token").data("token");
   return params;
  };

$('#investmentName').editable({

           type: 'text',
           url: '/',   
           send: 'always'

           });
});

</script>
```

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and PHP7 on XAMPP. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to add data-name in your a href tag.
Make sure you add data-name in your href
for e.g

```
<a href="#" id="investmentName" data-type="text" data-name="investment_name" data-pk="{{ $single_item->id }}" data-title="Edit investment">{!! $single_item->investment_name !!}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I added that to no avail. Still no response. I'm wondering if the libraries or the order they are loaded is off. The lack of error feels like the issue is outside of my code/page.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon an edit that made this work, just not sure why.

If instead of referring to the ID of the item, I give it a class name (change `id=""` to `class=""`) and refer to that in the Javascript, it now works. So the code changes I made were in the blade as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="investmentName" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ ....
```

and

```
$('.investmentName').editable({ ....
```

Hope this helps someone else. I'd still love to know why this makes the difference in my Laravel app since almost all of the example code I had been reading used the ID object reference, which didn't work.

*** UPDATE ***

Well, my delight was short-lived. While the stripped down code works in isolation, as soon as I add this to my primary app it fails, giving the following error ("scenario" is my blade name):

```
scenario:667 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scenario:667)
    at l (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.S (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
```

The line causing the error is:

`$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';` (or any reference to "defaults").

My app has the following header loads, and I suspect that there's a conflict with the JS library, but I've tried eliminating these as well to no avail - I'm shooting in the dark. Here's the complete header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
      content="IE=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
      name="viewport"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type"
      content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link href="{{ url('adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url('quickadmin/css') }}/select2.min.css"/>
<link href="{{ url('adminlte/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url('adminlte/css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url('adminlte/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any suggestions are very welcome as I'm stuck!

Comment: Well, my delight was short-lived. While the stripped down code works, as soon as I add this to my primary app it fails, giving the following error:

`scenario:667 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scenario:667)
    at l (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.S (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the offending conflict. I'm using **AdminLTE** and buried in an included header, that further included other files that had javascript includes, was a call to an older version of JQuery.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Commenting out this line resolved the conflict and it now works in my larger app. My original test pages didn't have the AdminLTE overhead attached.

All good now  :)